# view only specific div from a web page with web view

Tags: android, webview

Is there any way to any way to allow the user to only view a certain <div> with WebView?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse out that `<div>` and load only it into the `WebView` in the first place.

Beyond that, no. `WebView` displays whatever you hand it.

Answer (score 1):

This post is quite old, but check the excellent jsoup library for parsing and selecting html content.